# clients for signalR in native ios and android

Tags: ios, signalr, socketrocket

1) If I have to develop native IOS client for a server that uses SignalR can I use

[SocketRocket](https://github.com/square/SocketRocket) or [UnittWebSocketClient](http://code.google.com/p/unitt/wiki/UnittWebSocketClient)  ?

2) The client App does not use any browser will that matter ?

3) How is SignalR Different from [Superwebsocket](http://superwebsocket.codeplex.com/) or microsoft's websocket available in .net 4.5? Dont all of them support rfc6455 protocol ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For iOS and OSX you can use [Signalr-ObjC](https://github.com/DyKnow/SignalR-ObjC) its kept up to pretty well with the ongoing version of SignalR.

Comment: +1 We are using this library in a project at the moment and have had good experiences with it so far

Comment: Thanks @BenClayton for the input. since it has been a while since you have posted this, thought of querying for an update. did you ever have any bad experiences with this as far as now?

Comment: Hey @CoderKK. There was a while where it was crashing when the stream was closed 'incorrectly' at the other end, but for now the app is still working more than two years later.

Comment: That's great to hear. Thanks @BenClayton!.

Answer (score 7):

Microsoft has just released an Android client https://github.com/SignalR/java-client. For iOs you cant take a look at https://github.com/DyKnow/SignalR-ObjC.

Answer (score 3):

You can look at my project [SignalA](https://github.com/erizet/SignalA) for a native Android-client. <del>It's work in progress... :)</del> It's now updated to protocol version 1.2 which is used in the 1.0 release of SignalR.

Comment: Hello Erik, Is SignalA up-to-date with the latest SignalR release?. We are working on a project that potentially would require an android client and want to see which are the options. Thanks

Comment: Yes. SignalA supports protocol version 1.2, which is used in the latest release.